# Docker or Docker-compose for client app with Proxy

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose

I have a `react` app with `go` for the proxy. I am struggling between whether or not to use `docker-compose` or to use a single `Dockerfile`. Would like to get an opinion and why you think one or the other is better?
FYI, we use relative API paths from the client app.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running this as multiple containers – the React application is running a non-production development server, and the Go application just has an HTTP proxy to it – then you will probably find it much easier to run with Compose.

You probably don't want to run a dev server in production.  It's typical to use a tool like Webpack to compile the React application down to static files.  Once you do that, you can include those static files in the Go application container (or even embed them in the Go binary).  A Docker [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) can handle this case well, using a first stage `FROM node` to `RUN npm run build`, a second stage `FROM golang` that builds the binary, and a final stage `FROM ubuntu` that combines the parts for runtime.  At that point you will only have one container, and it's your choice whether it's more convenient to just `docker run` the container or wrap it in a `docker-compose.yml` file.

In any case you probably want to avoid configuring unnecessary things at deployment time.  Avoid specifying a Compose `command:` if you can, for example; don't use `volumes:` to inject or overwrite significant parts of the application.  If you have an involved `docker run` command it will be easier to re-run it if you rewrite it in Compose, but it'd be better still to just need fewer parameters to start the container.